# Dependent type and dependee in arguments to function in scala

Tags: scala, types

I want to do this in Scala:

```
def sum[T](seq: Seq[T]): T =
  seq match {
    case last :: Nil => last
    case head :: tail => head + sum(tail)
  }
```

But Scala complains that there is a type mismatch on `sum(tail)`: it is expecting a `String` but got a `T` - which doesn't sound right of course. I investigated a little, and it looks like Scala's type inference system can only infer that `tail` is of type `Seq[Any]`. Is that the issue? What is the correct way to write this in Scala?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler doesn't know if method `+` is available for type `T`. That business about `String` is misleading. It just defaults to assuming that `+` is supposed to be a `String` concatenation.

If you restrict `T` to be only some numeric type that can be added together then it will work.

```
def sum[T:Numeric](seq: Seq[T]): T =
  seq match {
    case last :: Nil => last
    case head :: tail => implicitly[Numeric[T]].plus(head, sum(tail))
  }
```

It can be expressed a little cleaner by adding an import.

```
def sum[T:Numeric](seq: Seq[T]): T = {
  import Numeric.Implicits._
  seq match {
    case last :: Nil => last
    case head :: tail => head + sum(tail)
  }
}
```

Also, `::` is intended for `List` operations. As it is your method will work for a `Seq` or a `List` but not, for example, `Vector`. Change `::` to the more generic `+:` and it will work with many more collection types like `Vector`, `Array`, etc.

Comment: `import Numeric.Implicits._` didn't seem to fix it for me.

Comment: Did you try the 1st fix before trying the `import` refinement? Both examples were tested on my IDE.

Comment: OK - now I got both to work. The first one is really ugly though. Thanks!